# Getting Error "Not a Data constructor" when defining a new datatype in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to define a new datatype for directions.
But, I am getting an error **"Not a data constructor: left"** when I load the file in ghci.

Here is the code snippet:

```
data Dir =   left
           | right 
           | up
           | down 

instance Show Dir where
 show left = "left"
 show right = "right"
 show up = "up"
 show down = "down"


-- initialpos is assumed to be valid one
move::Pos->Dir->Pos
move prevPos left = ( (-1)  $ fst prevPos  ,  snd prevPos)   
move prevPos right = ( (+1) $ fst prevPos ,  snd prevPos )
move prevPos up = ( fst prevPos, (+1) $ snd prevPos  )
move prevPos down = ( fst prevPos, (-1) $ snd prevPos )
```

Please help me in figuring out what is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignoring infix data constructors, a data constructor must begin with a capital letter.

```
data Dir = Left | Right | Up | Down
```

Comment: Thank you. I have changed the data constructor to use values like "North | South" etc.. Its now working. Also, when I tried to use Left | Right, ghci complained that it conflicts with the Left and Right from `Either` datatype

Answer (score 2):

As @chepner rightly points out, the data constructors should begin with capital letters. To address the next problem you run into i.e. `Left` and `Right` are ambiguous between your defined ones and those from `Either`, you can do this:

1. Explicitly import Prelude and hide `Either` type constructor to avoid the ambiguity. This will let you continue using all the other 'default' functions from `Prelude` without issue

   ```
   import Prelude hiding (Either(..)) --Everything except Either which causes ambiguity issues
   ```
2. (Optional) Do a qualified import of `Data.Either` if you wish to use it elsewhere in your code.

   ```
   import qualified Data.Either as E --You will be able to use Either by writing E.Either in your code
   ```

That said, you could avoid this trouble by renaming your data constructors if that is an option.

Comment: Indeed, hiding `Either` and defining your own `Left` and `Right` will very likely confuse other people reading your code.